# How can I locate the single buddypress forum post template?

Tags: posts, templates, buddypress, bbpress, forum

I have been trying for ages to locate the template that shows a single forum post template and I cannot find it.

Does anyone know where this is located?

Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to group forums, then buddypress ask to use bbPress instead. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I'm also not quite sure if this question is related to bbPress or BuddyPress, locating (plugin-) template files might always be the same:

An easy approach might be to call the [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) in a file which is definitely active (like `header.php`). The output will look something like this:

```
class="forum-archive bbpress archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-forum logged-in admin-bar"
```

If this is not possible one can print the location of the template file via an action. Simply put this snippet at the bottom of your `functions.php`:

```
function show_template_name() {
    global $template;
    print_r($template);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template_name');
```

Note: This will output the complete path to the current template file on every page! Do not use this on a live site! The output will look something like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/archive-forum.php
```

And finally a more sustainable approach might be to use a debug plugin like [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) which will add a Dropdown to the Admin Toolbar like this:

[image: Screenshot WordPress Toolbar, Query Monitor Plugin Dropdown]

Note: Even if this looks pretty, please consider that it will take a lot of resources and should also not be used on live sites.